# threaded variable propagation / inheritance

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, concurrency, sidekiq

I'm trying to communicate information to all child threads but not sibling threads. For example. If I am starting a threaded background job, I want to set a variable to true and have it be true for all threads the background job may spawn but not necessarily other background job threads.

How can I go about this?

Ruby 2.1.2
Rails 4.1.16